# Регулярное выражение BASH для калькулятора

Tags: linux, bash, posix

Нужно регулярное выражение для арифметических операций калькулятора, чтобы принимало символы / + - * в любом количестве.

Для целых и вещественных проблем не составило написать его, а вот для символов не получается.

```
^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$ для любых чисел

^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*[\/\+\*-]*$ - с нужными знаками, чего-то не хочет работать правильно
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тестировал в Notepad++
Я правильно понял, что вместо числа может быть символ типа a,x,y и.тд?

```
^(((\d*\.?\d*)|\w)([+-/*]))*((\d*\.?\d*)|\w)$
```

Если использование буквенных переменных не требуется, то тогда выражение будет таким:

```
^((\d*\.?\d*)([+-/*]))*(\d*\.?\d*)$
```